# vs 2017 static library "No Such File or Directory"

Tags: c++, linker, directory, static-libraries

I'm having problems importing my custom static library into my project. I have my library in the same solution as the project that I am trying to include it in.

In the VC++ Directory section of the project properties I have put "$(SolutionDir);" in the Include Directories and "$(SolutionDir)Debug\;" in the Library Directories. It is my understanding that the "$(SolutionDir);" is a macro that defines the root directory right? As the library shares the same solution as the project it also shares the same root directory and the .lib file that is created is in the Debug folder of the root directory.

In the Linker/Input section, I have put "GameEngine.lib;" in the Additional Dependencies. "GameEngine.lib" is the file name of the .lib that is in the Debug folder of the root directory.

When I'm trying to include anything from the library it just doesn't even recognise it as existing when writing:

`#include <GameEngine/Rendering/Model.h>`

Doing it the way below shows that it can actually find the file, meaning the path exists and is correct but I get linker errors doing it this way.

`#include "../GameEngine/Rendering/Model.h"`

I am using Visual Studios 2017.

Link to GitHub repo: https://github.com/TheHoester/OpenGLGameEngine.git

Thank you

[image: Solution Directory]

[image: GameEngine library Directory]

[image: Project Directory]

[image: Include Directories]

[image: Linker Input]

Comment: at a guess your "ect." file isn't in the "$(SolutionDir)\GameEngine" folder. You can see what the macros resolve to in the visual studio properties editors

Comment: "ect." isn't the real file name, I realise now that I meant "etc.", it would be swapped out with whatever I was trying to call from the library, for instance <GameEngine/Rendering/Model.h>

Comment: My point was that without knowing your complete directory structure its very difficult to provide any help.

Comment: Sorry, well the file im trying to include is <GameEngine/Rendering/Model.h>, but starting it off GameEngine doesn't even provide an autocomplete option, but "../GameEngine/Rendering/Model.h" doesn't create any errors but i do get linker errors with it, i've updated the question to reflect that

Comment: We still don't know your complete directory structure. where is the solution file? where are your project files? where is your source code?

Comment: The solution is just in a folder in my documents, in the solution, there are two projects, one is the static library, I'll mention that the library was originally an application project that I converted over, I believe it is done correctly as the .lib is being created in the debug folder of the solution rather than the .exe that it use to. All the GameEngine .h and .cpp files are sorted into folders, with one of them being Rendering as mentioned before, within the GameEngine project folder and they are namespaced to mirror the file structure.

Comment: The other project that i want to include the game engine in has only only one .cpp and .h file while im trying to figure out how to include the library

Comment: I still don't know what your folder layout is, maybe a screenshot of explorer showing all the folders might help?

Comment: No problem, was just on that, is there any more screenshots youd like?

Comment: OK, looks correct, did you try looking at what visual studio is resolving `$(SolutionDir)` to in the properties editor?

Comment: I'm not sure how you do that. I was thinking it might have something to do with $(SolutionDir) but it is being used as the part of the output directory path in properties.

Comment: When you set the properties in visual studio there is a second box right below the editing box which shows the actual values of the properties e.g.: https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC816784.jpeg

Comment: Ah I see, this is the file path it is using for $(SolutionDir) "C:\Users\User\Documents\Projects\OpenGLGameEngine\", which is the correct path to where the solution directory is located. Using $(SolutionDir)Debug\ also has the path of "C:\Users\User\Documents\Projects\OpenGLGameEngine\Debug\"

Comment: And you've set the same settings on every project and every configuration?

Comment: oh should I add them to the GameEngine library too?

Comment: you should add it to whichever projects need to use the `"GameEngine/Rendering/Model.h"` includes, if the game engine project uses `#include "Rendering/Model.h"` internally then you wont need to update its settings

Comment: Everything in the GameEngine works fine and builds correctly, all the includes there work. I have included the directory paths like I've stated in the original post and yet I am unable to include the GameEngine files to the project, (the project called "1_Cube" in the pictures) im going to add the pictures of the directories to see what you think

Comment: It all looks OK to me, no doubt its something really obvious but its difficult to debug remotely

Comment: if i put it in a github repository would you be able to take a look at it? I would be grateful if you have the time

Comment: ok, I can do that

Comment: I've added a link to the github repo in the original post, its still pushing at the time of writing this but should be on there soon. Thank you

Comment: Alright its finally pushed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you set the directories for all build configurations. You have only set the include directories for the "x64" platform so building the "Win32" platform won't work. After adding the directories to the "Win32" platform your project builds correctly.

Note that it is more usual to use "VC++ Directories" for system includes and libraries and to use "C/C++/General/Additional Include Directories" and "C/C++/Linker/General/Additional Library Directories" for linking to your own libraries. There isn't any problem that I'm aware of for using the "VC++ Directories" settings though, just make sure not to modify any of the existing paths in there.

Comment: Awesome, that works perfectly, will have to remember that in future, Thank you so much for your help, I would have been stuck on this forever otherwise.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. I did mention making sure all the configurations were the same a few hours ago....

Comment: sorry that's my bad, i must have miss understood what you meant by configurations, i would up vote this but unfortunately my rep aint high enough